# How can I have different colours for the head separation line with the scrlayer-scrpage package for even and odd pages?

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

I have tried now for a long time and couldn't figure out how to implement different colours for the head separation line depending on whether the page is odd or even.

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper,
titlepage,
toc=listof,            
toc=bibliography,       
headings=standardclasses,       
%headings=big,
chapterprefix=true,            
numbers=noenddot,               
twoside=semi,               
]{scrreport}        

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}


\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\large{\normalfont{\textsc{\thepage}}}}
\rehead{\large{\normalfont{\textsc{{\headmark}}}}}

\rohead{\large{\normalfont{\textsc{\thepage}}}}
\lohead{\large{\normalfont{\textsc{{\headmark}}}}}


\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\color{blue}}
\addtokomafont{footsepline}{\color{blue}}
\setheadsepline{2}
\setfootsepline{2}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is

```latex
\KOMAoptions{
  onpsoddpage={\colorlet{headsepline}{green}},
  onpsevenpage={\colorlet{headsepline}{red}}
}
\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\color{headsepline}}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  %11pt,% default
  %a4paper,% default
  titlepage,
  toc=listof,
  toc=bibliography,
  headings=standardclasses,
  %headings=big,% default
  chapterprefix=true,
  numbers=noenddot,
  twoside=semi,
]{scrreport}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[
  automark,
  headsepline=2pt,% <- changed
  footsepline=2pt% <- changed
]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}% <- changed
\ihead{\headmark}% <- changed
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\large\scshape}% <- added
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}% <- added

\KOMAoptions{
  onpsoddpage={\colorlet{headsepline}{green}},% green on odd pages
  onpsevenpage={\colorlet{headsepline}{red}}% red on even pages
}
\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\color{headsepline}}% <- changed
\addtokomafont{footsepline}{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional remark: `\setheadsepline` and `\setfootsepline` are depraceted. Use options `headsepline=2pt` and `footsepline=2pt` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, you probably saved me a lot of time! I have now directly tried to convert this for colouring section titles and chapter titles as well, but this wont transfer. I am a beginner when it comes to Latex programming, so do you mind sharing how this would go if I wanted to the same for sections and chapter etc.?

Comment: You can upvote (and maybe accept) my answer, if it solves your issue. Regarding the sections and chapters ask a new question and explain how the desired result should look like. At the moment I do not understand what you want to do.

Comment: I already tried to upvote your answer, but since I have a new account it won't let me until I have collected 15 points. Thank you very much once again and I have now marked your answer as the solution, I might post a new question for the remainder of functions I wanted to implement.